# Simple Range statement not working. Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get why my simple code doesn't work. All I'm trying to do is to insert a chart using my own range variable, as I remember it the code should run but I get a 1004 error : Application defined or object defined error.

What may be the issue?

Edit: Change the initiation of the wRange object to make it qualified. Error is still happening though

Code
EDIT: Have updated the code after all the comments¨

```
Private Sub tester()

    Dim wSheet As Worksheet: Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MainWindow")
    Dim wShape As Shape
    Dim wRange As Range: Set wRange = wSheet.Range("A26")

    Set wShape = wSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered, wSheet.Range(wRange).Left, wSheet.Range(wRange).Top, _
         wSheet.Range(wRange, wRange.Offset(0, 20)).Width, wSheet.Range(wRange, wRange.Offset(19, 0)).Height)

'Original code that I'm trying to modify, this one works without errors in a classmodule
'    Set wshape = wst.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered, wst.Range("A26").Left, wst.Range("A26").Top, _
'    wst.Range("A26:U26").Width, wst.Range("A26:A45").Height)

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes error? Debug the program using F8 key.

Comment: The error occurs at the last line after declaring the nArray

Comment: Unqualified or poorly/incorrectly qualified range object is the #1 cause of this error. There are literally hundreds of this exact same question here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, now I know about unqualified range object. I changed the code so that the wRange object is qualified. But the error still occurs

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use good programming practice and use code with context:

```
Dim wSheet As Worksheet: Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("SheetName")
Dim wRange As Range: Set wRange = wSheet.Range("A26")
```

See: [Range Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

**[EDIT]**

@uncool, thank you for clarification.

You need to select range where you want to put chart. So...

```
Set wRange = wSheet.Range("A26:C40")
wRange.Select
'here code to add chart
```

Now, you should be able to add new chart ;)

Comment: Does **AddChart2** is an Excel function/method? Refer this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820981%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Yepp. Changing the range object for simple range destination e.g "A1:U1" makes the code executable.

Comment: OK, it's newer version of Excel. I found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228277%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Cool. :) Any suggestions on the application defined error? I'm self-learned again, but as I see it there's nothing wrong with the syntax or declarations or variables/objects?

Comment: Thank for the reply Maciej, funny thing is though that I've tried that and it generated the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure you're using code with context? Still the initialization of **wSheet** is wrong in your code.

Comment: I have now updated the code. Now the error is: Method "Range" of object _Worksheet failed. I have searched on google and as David says the issue is almost that the range/cells are unqualified. But mine are right?

Comment: **wRange** does not refer to *A26:A45* cells.
Please, read this book: https://books.google.pl/books?id=0wCb6tt-8rIC&pg=PT277&lpg=PT277&dq=vba+excel+shapes+addchart2&source=bl&ots=adMRMX4nuh&sig=GEh8k5CSU6Zd5Aqvhq83Nvj1hvM&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=-YKlVOqxFMTjywOigIKYCg&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=vba%20excel%20shapes%20addchart2&f=false

Comment: Well, but I still get the error if I replace wRange, wRange.offset with "A26:A45". I've actually read large parts of it, but have forgotten.